# Libpqxx Undefined reference using CMake

Tags: cmake, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conan, libpqxx

I'm using CLion (which forces CMake) with the WSL toolstack.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(conana)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake-build-debug/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()
set(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/mnt/c/Users/b/src/libpqxx/")

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(conana ${SOURCES})
#target_link_libraries(${project} ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Produces the error

```
====================[ Build | conana | Debug ]==================================
/usr/bin/cmake --build /mnt/c/Users/b/CLionProjects/conana --target conana -- -j 8
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/conana.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/conana
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/conana.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/home/buddha/.conan/data/libpqxx/7.0.1/bincrafters/stable/package/cfd7bc19fdc01c984df6e1fe4e7d6856d5f9b76a/include/pqxx/strconv.hxx:76: undefined reference to `pqxx::internal::demangle_type_name[abi:cxx11](char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/conana.dir/build.make:84: bin/conana] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/conana.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/conana.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: conana] Error 2
```

I appreciate your help.  Uncommenting the `target_link_libraries` gives a "not managed by this CMake" error.

Comment: It might be that you were linking with a different libstdc++ than the one you used to install the conan packages. Make sure to read the output when you ``conan install``. The default one is ``libstdc++`` and not ``libstdc++11`` because of historic reasons and compatibility with older distros. You can change the default libcxx setting as described in https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html with ``conan profile update settings.compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 default``. I would love to know if this works, even if you finally went without Conan.

Comment: if I try it, I will let you know.  appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up removing conan and working through the solution in the libpqxx issues [here](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/issues/314).  The CMakeLists.txt was ultimately

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(conana)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_library(PQXX_LIB pqxx REQUIRED)
find_library(PQ_LIB pq REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(conana ${SOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(conana ${PQXX_LIB} ${PQ_LIB})
```

Which also solved some issues immediately following the connection.  Hope this helps someone.